# Otimizar impressão de grandes resultados do SQL-Server através do ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, json, asp

Hoje tenho uma página em ASP clássico com um chain-select não convencional (leia-se "armengado") que retorna um select populado com alguns dados de um banco de dados sql-server (2005).

Seleciono o prédio e retorna o números de andares hábeis para entrega nesse prédio; simples.

Funciona muito bem hoje; O problema é que em breve terei que adicionar mais de 600 linhas nessa base e a consulta vai ficar muito lenta (uma vez que o ASP precisa imprimir todos os dados na página antes do javascript pegar e levar para o select.

Preciso saber se existe uma forma melhor de buscar esses dados - Eu consigo fazer uma interação **SQL-SERVER -> JSON** para que o dados venham mais rapidamente? Existe uma outra maneira em ASP para popular a página mais rapidamente? Preciso de melhores práticas nesse exemplo especifico.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="PREDIOS">PREDIOS</label>
    <%set RS = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
    RS.Open "select distinct PREDIOS from PI_AUTOCOMPLETAR_LOC ORDER BY PREDIOS",conn,1%>
    <select id="PREDIOS" name="PREDIOS" class="form-control" onchange="venha_lista();">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <%If RS.bof And RS.eof Then
    response.write "Lista Vazia"
    Else
    While not RS.eof    
    Response.Write "<option value='"&RS("PREDIOS").value&"'>"&RS("PREDIOS").value&"</option>"
    RS.movenext
    Wend
    End If%>
     </select>
    </div>
<div id="ANDAR"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
function venha_lista() {
    $.post("consulta_loc/atualizar_ANDAR.asp", $("#leva_servico").serialize(), function (data) {
        $("#ANDAR").html(data);
    });
};
```

**atualizar_ANDAR.asp**

```
<%set rs = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
PREDIO = REQUEST("PREDIO")
IF PREDIO = ""  THEN
PREDIO = "%"
end if
RS.Open "select distinct ANDAR from PI_AUTOCOMPLETAR_LOC WHERE PREDIO = '"&PREDIO&"' ORDER BY ANDAR",conn,1 %>
<select id="ANDAR" name="ANDAR" class="form-control">
<option value="">Selecione</option>
<% WHILE NOT RS.EOF %>
<option value="<%Response.write rs("ANDAR")%>"><%Response.write rs("ANDAR")%></option>
<% RS.MoveNext 
    WEND    %>
</select>
```

Comment: Ao invés de escrever todo o código html em conjunto com o dado necessário, trabalhe com objetos JSON. Você vai retornar pouquíssimo volume de dados. Existem hoje funções que você executa a query nesta função e a mesma já retorna o objeto Json, exemplo: `QueryToJson(sql, conn)`. O Jquery compreende JSON o que facilita o trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

Uma saída é usar o `response.flush` dentro do loop.

"Sete" `response.buffer=true` no início do seu código. No loop peça o `response.flush` para ir escrevendo o conteúdo do script a cada passo desse loop...